# React Native and US export regulations

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store-connect, axios

I want to publish my React Native app on the Apple App Store and given that I'm using HTTPS/SSL I'm required to upload the ERN approval document. I have a question regarding the question four of export compliance questions:

> 4th Question: Does your product implement standard encryption algorithm(s) instead of or in addition to using or accessing the encryption in Apple OS?

Given that I'm using React Native and the library [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) for https requests should I respond "YES" to this question? I'm not sure because I'm not using the standard Apple OS for this purpose...

Thanks a lot, I'm quite lost in all this bureaucratic stuff

Answer (score 1):

I am not a legal expert, but I would argue **no**, as axios simply uses the HTTPS npm package, which (I guess, haven't found it on github) may use the XMLHttpRequest implementation. This implementation relies on a native implementation in Objective-C, using the Apple OS encryptions.